# Lining numbers in mathnormal

Tags: fonts, math-mode, typography, math-operators

Is there a simple way to have lining numbers (instead of old style ones) using `\mathnormal{}` ?
I want `$\mathnormal{abc123}$` to look like `$abc123$`.

My problem is that I have an operator `\Declaremathop[1]{Op^{#1}}` with an argument that can be a number or a letter, and in both case I want the argument to look just like the default math font (using `$...$`), but :

- with `\Declaremathoperator[1]{Op^{#1}}` I get roman letter ;
- with `\Declaremathop[1]{Op^\mathnormal{#1}}` I get old style numbers.

Edit : the operator is actually in two parts, eg `\Declaremathoperator{Op^{#1}Bla}` that's why I cannot isolate the argument out of the operator declaration.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this but I will use it from now on.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand; can you add some code?

Comment: The operator I want is of the following form : `{Op^{arg}Bla}` with {arg} being a digit or a letter.

Comment: And `arg` can vary?

Comment: Yes it can (it is an argument in my operator declaration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `\Declaremathop`.

Do it indirectly:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \operatorname
\newcommand{\Op}[1]{\operatorname{Op}^{#1}}
```

Then `\Op{a}` and `\Op{1}` will do the right thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \operatorname

\newcommand{\Op}[1]{\operatorname{Op}^{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\Op{a}\ne\Op{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a “two part” operator, just exploit the fact that TeX inserts a thin space between consecutive operators, so we can remove that space with `\!`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \operatorname

\newcommand{\OpBla}[1]{%
  \operatorname{Op}^{#1}\!\operatorname{Bla}%
}

\begin{document}
$\OpBla{a}\ne\OpBla{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't work for my purpose (I should have been more precise, I will edit the question).

Answer (score 1):

> [image: normal exponent in math op]

Update to account for `egreg`'s test with a minus sign which should (perhaps) not be converted into a hyphen:

> [image: normal exponentn in math op 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\DeclareMathOp}[2]
    {\DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{\qopname\relax o{Op^{\fam-1 #2}bla}}}

%\newcommand{\DeclareMathOp}[2]{\DeclareMathOperator{#1}{Op^{\fam-1 #2}bla}}

\DeclareMathOp \testletter {abc}

\DeclareMathOp \testdigits {123}

\DeclareMathOp \testmixed {a1b2c3}

\DeclareMathOp{\testminus}{a-b}

\begin{document}
\Huge

$\testletter\neq \testdigits\neq \testmixed $

$\testminus$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\DeclareMathOp{\testminus}{a-b}`.

Comment: @egreg but this is the normal effect of the `\newmcodes@` disputable `amsmath` macro. I will add an alternative.

Comment: Disputable or not (I don't think it is), it doesn't give the correct output.

Comment: @egreg ok, `\newmcodes@` is not _that_ disputable, its main defect (corrected by `lualatex-math`) being to make Unicode assignments to the minus sign break `\DeclareMathOperator` but this is naturally up to the Unicode `TeX` systems to provide the patch (as done by `lualatex-math`). The `disputable` part I always keep is mind is for `\newmcodes@` to have hard coded the use of mathgroup zero, whereas on the other hand `\operator@font` is customizable, and does not necessarily hardcode it. Hence potential for mismatch. This is a bug in my view.