# Why do numbers in \mathnormal not match numbers without it?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Why do numbers typeset with `\mathnormal{...}` not give the same result as numbers typeset without it? The documentation [here](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf) leads me to think they should be the same. I've searched this site and the closest question I've found is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181030/218142) but this specific issue is never addressed.  I don't need a fix; I only want to know why the difference exists.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\(0123456789\)

\( \mathnormal{0123456789} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled MWE]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

math mode consists (in classic TeX) of 16 math font families and each character is assigned a default family and optional allowed to vary the family in the scope of a command like `\mathbf` or `\mathnormal`.

In the default setup digits come from the operator family (normally upright roman font) but `\mathnormal` forces the default math italic font used for letters and that is where the old style numbers are in the default tex encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

As you can see in the [Font Guide](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf) (on page 11), `\mathnormal` uses the `cmm` font family. This stands for Computer Modern Math Italic (page 4). As David explained, numbers in regular math are taken from the `operators` family, which is `cmr` (Computer Modern Roman).

With the `fonttable` package you can see the glyphs for the different families, using the attributes from the table on page 11 of the Font Guide as arguments for the `\xfonttable` command. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\xfonttable{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\xfonttable{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\end{document}
```

`cmr` numbers:

[image]

`cmm` numbers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Package-writing and Unicode fonts add further overlays and permutations to the conventions:

[image: sample]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}[Colour=red]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
\begin{document}

0123456789 abc ABC αβγ

\(0123456789 abc ABC αβγ\)

\( \mathnormal{0123456789 αβγ} αβγ\)

\( \mathrm{0123456789 αβγ} αβγ\)

\( \textrm{0123456789 αβγ} αβγ\)

\( \mathit{0123456789 αβγ} αβγ\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still in the process of learning about unicode fonts.