# Macro for removing font changes that returns number in default font in KaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, color, katex

So [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555081/why-do-numbers-in-mathnormal-not-match-numbers-without-it) explains why `\mathnormal` doesn't actually return numbers in the default font, but doesn't offer any solution for achieving this.

I'm working with KaTeX and have a set of macros for bolding & colouring symbols, but would like to be able to define an `\unstyle` macro that exempts part of an expression. For example, if `\blue{}` applies `\boldsymbol` and `{\color{blue}}` to its argument, I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
\blue{x^3 + 2x \unstyle{+ x} - 12}
```

such that everything except the "+ x" is in `boldsymbol` and `colour{blue}` and the "+ x" is in the default ("normal" math).

NB. double invocation of `\blue`, like:

```
\blue{x^3 + 2x} + x \blue{- 12}
```

does not solve the issue, as it breaks the rendering of `+` and `-` as operators:

[image: last term's addition operator has incorrect spacing]

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this? I've played around with every combination of the  [fonts options](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#style-color-size-and-font) available on KaTeX; however, the ones that resolve the issue for numbers change the font for the letters and vice-versa. I'm surprised that there isn't an *actual* "normalmath" (i.e. `defaultmath`) option.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: katex is javascript rather than tex so not really on topic but in latex assuming `\blue{..}` was defined as `\textcolor{blue}{...}` then you could restore the binary operator spacing by adding empty math atoms `{}` so `x \blue{{}+12}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for fixing the spacing. I wasn't sure about KaTeX -- noticed there wasn't a tag. What is the process for defining scope on new topics for TeX SE? Seems to me there is some scope of La/TeX-related questions that wouldn't be any more inappropriate here than other flavours of TeX (forgive me if this is naive: I am not very knowledgeable about the inner workings of any of these systems). I would be interested in helping this effort, if I could.

Comment: there has been much discussion about mathjax and that has the same issues about emulating latex math syntax but not using tex. see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/how-do-we-feel-about-mathjax-jsmath-other-spin-offs for example or the [tag:mathjax] tag wiki

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand\unstyle[1]{\textcolor{normalcolor}{#1}}

$\blue{x^3 + 2x \unstyle{+ x} - 12}$

$x^3+2x+x-12$
```

[image]

Of course, this doesn't work in standard LaTeX, but it could be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\unstyle}[1]{\begingroup\normalcolor#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}

$\blue{x^3 + 2x \unstyle{+ x} - 12}$

$x^3+2x+x-12$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg; however, the main challenge has been to undo the effect of `boldsymbol`, not the colour, alone. My apologies: excluding the colour would've made that clearer, but I didn't think of it, as the actual commands also apply colour.