# How to Restore Default Operator Spacing When Applying Styling like \boldsymbol or \color in a Math Environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, color, math-operators, boldsymbol

It seems that applying styling to math operators messes up the operator spacing *e.g.*

```
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    3 \sin(x) \\ 
    3 \boldsymbol{\sin(x)} \\ 
    3 {\color{red}\sin(x)}
  \end{aligned}
\]
```

Results in:
[image: apply colour or boldsymbol eliminates the spacing before the sine]

How can one preserve the appropriate spacing of operators, in such cases?

Comment: What would be the reason for `3\boldsymbol{\sin(x)}`?

Comment: This was just an example of some styling. Should `\boldsymbol` not be used for math operators? I use colours to emphasize steps, in math solutions; however, just using `\color` can result in difficult-to-read materials (esp. in printed materials), so I beef up the symbol with a bold font (I believe I use a bold font family for the command, in reality, but I was doing this online so used the first thing that came to mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something reminded me of David Carlisle comment on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584300/macro-for-removing-font-changes-that-returns-number-in-default-font-in-katex), and I realized that a similar solution would work here, *viz.* inserting an empty math atom `{}` inside the styling command will restore the default spacing, *i.e.*

```
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    3 \sin(x) \\ 
    3 \boldsymbol{ {} \sin(x)} \\ 
    3 { {} \color{red}\sin(x)}
  \end{aligned}
\]
```

will result in normal spacing:

[image]

Given that this wasn't the actual focus of that question, I figured I'd share this solution here, in case it may be of use to others.